# I have the minimum Y value. I want to find the corresponding X value from the list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a very big file and contains data in the format of {x,y}. I got the **minimum Y value** by using

```
data[[All, 2]] // Min[#] &
```

Now I want to get the **X value** corresponding to the minimum Y value.
How can I get it?
Thanks a lot for your help ..!

Comment: `MinimalBy[data,Last]`

Comment: `SortBy[data, Last] [[1, 1]]`

Comment: @MarcoB Wouldn't `Sort` take much more time in general case?

Comment: @BlacKow that's an interesting point. I ran some timings and I posted them as an answer, since it was too long for a comment.

Comment: Thank you very much. Really both are working as I newbee in mathematica I did not find any differecnes on their performance.

Comment: //Min[#]& could be written shorter as //Min.

Comment: What to do in the case of a duplicate minimum Y?

Comment: This question has been asked and answered many times before, both for the case of a single value and multiple values, and for both minimum and maximum values.  (Though understanding one should give one a solution to the other.)  Unfortunately I can only pick one duplicate so I chose the one with the lowest post ID.  See comment below for more related questions.

Comment: Related:
[(1342)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1342/121),
[(2177)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2177/121),
[(2434)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2434/121),
[(7679)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7679/121),
[(10143)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10143/121),
[(19300)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19300/121),
[(31385)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31385/121),
[(31878)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31878/121),
[(37594)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37594/121)

Comment: Related (continued): [(57207)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57207/121), [(69971)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69971/121), [(77136)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77136/121), [(83602)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83602/121)

Answer (score 17):

One solution that is three to four times as fast as the fastest solution so far (halirutan's compiled `Do` loop) is:

```
data[[Ordering[data[[All, 2]], 1], 1]]
```

The obligatory timings:

```
MinimalBy[data, Last][[1, 1]] // RepeatedTiming
SortBy[data, Last][[1, 1]] // RepeatedTiming
SortBy[data, {Last}][[1, 1]] // RepeatedTiming
TakeSmallestBy[data, Last, 1][[1, 1]] // RepeatedTiming
minByLast[data] // RepeatedTiming
data[[Ordering[data[[All, 2]], 1], 1]] // RepeatedTiming
```

Output for random seed 5:

> ```
> {2.0, 362.181}
>
> {0.53, 362.181}
>
> {0.49, 362.181}
>
> {0.756, 362.181}
>
> {0.12, 362.181}
>
> {0.04, {362.181}}
> ```

Random seed 42:

> ```
> {1.7, 375.714}
>
> {0.50, 375.714}
>
> {0.46, 375.714}
>
> {0.78, 375.714}
>
> {0.12, 375.714}
>
> {0.032, {375.714}}
> ```

I note that even if you compile halirutan's code with `CompilationTarget->"C"`  `Ordering` is still almost twice as fast.

Comment: `Ordering[#,1] ` is probably treated as special case, because `data[[Ordering[data[[All, 2]], 2], 1]]` is almost 10 times slower...

Comment: That was my first thought, but I dropped it without testing because we need to compare the last elements. My thought was that this makes it slower. It seems my decision was premature. +1

Comment: @BlacKow `Ordering[#,1]` can be seen as the first stage in an unfinished sort. `Ordering[#,2]` is a successive stage, so necessarily must be slower.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Is it documented anywhere what sorting algorithm is used?

Comment: It should be something like `data[[Ordering[data[[All, 2]], 1], 1]][[1]]` or `data[[Sequence @@ Ordering[data[[All, 2]], 1], 1]]` to get the same output format (without the `List`) as the other methods.

Comment: @BlacKow I don't  know where this is documented, though I seem to remember having read about this somewhere.

Answer (score 13):

As it seem a compiled stupid `Do` loop is a viable alternative and still the fastest on my machine:

```
minByLast = Compile[{{data, _Real, 2}},
  Module[{min = First[data]},
   Do[
    If[Last[min] > Last[d], min = d], {d, data}];
   First[min]
   ]
  ]
```

And in comparison with the methods proposed it still seems to win

```
SeedRandom[5]
data = RandomReal[1000, {2000000, 2}];

MinimalBy[data, Last][[1, 1]] // RepeatedTiming
SortBy[data, Last][[1, 1]] // RepeatedTiming
SortBy[data, {Last}][[1, 1]] // RepeatedTiming
TakeSmallestBy[data, Last, 1][[1, 1]] // RepeatedTiming
minByLast[data] // RepeatedTiming
```

> [image: comparison]

Comment: I can understand how your compiled version is the fastest. But how non-compiled `SortBy` is faster than non-compiled `MinimalBy` is beyond me...

Comment: @BlacKow I think it is even worse with the new `TakeSmallestBy` function which should  outperform all other solutions, because it is specifically made for, well, taking the smallest element from a list..

Comment: Your `minByLast` is the fasted even when the time needed by `Compile` is included in the timing measurement.

Answer (score 9):

@BlackKow raised an interesting point about speed of the two solutions we proposed in comments. Out of curiosity I timed the two solutions on a random data set:

```
SeedRandom[5]
data = RandomReal[1000, {2000000, 2}];

MinimalBy[data, Last] // RepeatedTiming
SortBy[data, Last][[1, 1]] // RepeatedTiming
SortBy[data, {Last}][[1, 1]] // RepeatedTiming

(* Out:
{1.68, {{362.181, 0.000374484}}}
{0.507, 362.181}
{0.473, 362.181}
*)
```

It seems that `SortBy` is still faster than `MinimalBy`. The stable sort version (third option) is slightly faster still, since it doesn't go into breaking ties after the sort-by-last has been completed.

Comment: Whaaat? How this can be true? Care to share insights why? `MinimalBy` should take O(N)...

Comment: `TakeSmallestBy[data, Last, 1]`

Comment: @chuy I have to say it is embarrassing that a function like `TakeSmallestBy`, introduced in version 10.1 is twice as slow as a `SortBy` and 4x slower than a simple `Do` loop written in less than a minute. This makes such things nothing more then syntactic sugar.

Comment: @halirutan I can't disagree that it _should_ be the fastest.

Answer (score 6):

My <del>*two*</del> one candidate:

```
SeedRandom[5]
data = RandomReal[1000, {2000000, 2}];

(* First@Extract[data, Ordering[data[[All, 2]], 1]] // RepeatedTiming *) (* Sjoerd's *)
First@Nearest[#2 -> #1, Min[#2]] & @@ Transpose[data] // RepeatedTiming
(*
  {0.038, 362.181}  (* Didnt' read Sjoerd's answer carefully enough first *)
  {0.029, 362.181}
*)
```

Sorry about that Sjoerd!

Comment: `Nearest` was improved in V10.1.

Comment: No problem, and `Nearest` has become very fast indeed. In v9 the same code is almost 20 times slower. +1

Comment: I closed this question because it has been asked in various forms many times.  (See links above.)  We now how many good answers scattered around the site.  I wonder if this method would be better posted in an older Q&A?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks. `Nearest` isn't as fast as `Pick` in the two closest questions,  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10143 and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/900.  And, to my mind, `Pick` seems clearer.  (I answered one question with this method, but just checked, and `Pick` is faster under certain conditions.) If you think I should add it to another question (of the two I mentioned, say), please suggest it and I will do it.